# EF Core ForeignKey attribute - how to make it nullable

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

I'm using EF Core to create a "MenuItem" table, which may be linked to a parent (of "MenuItem") like so ...

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public int MenuItemId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentMenuItemId")]
    public virtual MenuItem Parent { get; set; }
}
```

ParentMenuItemId gets created as NOT NULL - how can I define it so Parent may be null (for root level MenuItem records)?

Comment: `public int? MenuItemId { get; set; }` and `public virtual MenuItem? Parent` ??

Comment: but the public int MenuItemId { get; set; } is the primary key of the current record, and Parent is a link to another record (also MenuItem) which would be a foreign key ... so isn't adding public int? MenuItemId { get; set; } saying that the primary key is nullable?

Comment: I think you can just set the parent as MenuItem? And leave the PK as Int

Comment: EFC 3.0 is quite old to recall conventions. But I think in all EFC versions this should create optional (nullable) FK property/column, except if you have NRT enabled, in which case you have to make the navigation property nullable, e.g. `MenuItem? Parent`.

Answer (score 0):

well, it's easy. all you have to do is this putting a `?` after defining type of object like this:

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public int? MenuItemId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentMenuItemId")]
    public virtual MenuItem Parent { get; set; }
}
```

but, you need to make sure there is a no such as `[Required]` tags on that relation object.

Comment: The public int MenuItemId { get; set; } is the primary key of the existing record - not the foreign key

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modelbuilder

```
mb.Entity<MenuItem> 
        .HasOne(o1 => o1.Parent)  
        .WithOne(o2 => o2.MenuItem)
        .IsRequired(false);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-composite-key%2Csimple-key#manual-configuration